# How multithreading works

Tags: java, multithreading

I have very basic question in my mind about multi threading.If we run 10 thread at a time so at single instance only one thread will be active and switching between threads takes place or more than one thread can run at a single instance of time?

Comment: Can you rephrase this?  Right now it makes little to no sense.  Also, please show what research you've done.  SO is not your research assistant.

Comment: If you SEE the CPU config then you see something like 4 Thread 2 Core. This means 4 thread at time. I thing if you run more then 4 thread at a time then it will be postponed in CLR.

Comment: Read this http://superuser.com/questions/329904/what-are-threads-and-what-do-they-do-in-the-processor If your CPU limited to 4 thread then it will not run more then 4 thread at a single time.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of a question on SE/Super User: http://superuser.com/questions/329904/what-are-threads-and-what-do-they-do-in-the-processor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on both your hardware and on your OS. If you have fewer cores than threads then the OS will likely interleave those threads, that is, every time one of them performs for example an IO operation or every time it finishes its time slice it gets switched for a different thread.

Also, every core runs one thread of execution. That's what multiple cores are for. This is usually mixed with the time slicing behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your CPU and program design. If you have a Quad Core PC, you could have 8 threads running simultaneously.

Comment: This answer could be misleading. I assume you are talking about Intel's Hyper-Threading technology. In which case, you should read this: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/hyperthreading-technology-explained/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the hardware. Many current processor chips incorporate more than one CPU, and a CPU may itself be able to interleave a couple of threads. A large server may have dozens of processor chips. On such a system, all 10 threads could run truly simultaneously.

Comment: A single CPU (core) might even run more than a couple of threads, depending on the type.  Consider the UltraSPARC T2 processor, which runs 8 threads per processor core, for example.

Answer (score 0):

only a single thread runs at a time .the processor switches over them quickly. for eg consider a text editor with spell chk..

u type-thats one thread
the prog chks fr errors- thats another thread

now if they are multithreaded , the whole process will get space in the memory and then the different threads will execute concurrently